# Microfiche-based solution for document storage

Tags: data-storage

As a local government, we generate lots of paper documents and currently are experiencing issues typical with storing them in paper form.

There are parts to this:
1. Millions of OLD documents going back decades that need to be scanned and
2. The newer documents generated by the various government departments yearly. So the amount of documents being scanned per day will depend on the cost of the solution.
The goal is the do a thousand documents per day

I know a digital solution would be best, but for judicial reasons, I can only store them on microfiche. So, I am researching an enterprise (both hardware & software) solution for storing/archiving paper documents.